# In Golang, json decoder returning an empty struct but ioutil.ReadAll shows the message

Tags: go

The response struct is as follows:

```
type Response struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
}
```

The code is as follows:

```
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))

response := &Response{}
json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(response)
fmt.Println("response struct:", response)
```

The output is as follows:

```
response Body: {"Message":"success"}

response struct: &{}
```

As we can see, the response body string is fine and contains the json strin. But when I try to decode the response body to a json, I get an empty struct.

I already have the Message field exported in the struct so that the json package has access to it. What am I still missing here ?

Comment: Duplicate but too lazy too look it up.

Comment: The duplicate ones are the ones where the field is not exported.

Comment: No, consuming the body for debug printing and wondering why decoding it once more yields empty is common too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have read `resp.Body` before the JSON `Decode` then it has no input to decode.

Try only -

```
response := &Response{}
json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(response)
fmt.Println("response struct:", response)
```

Comment: Yes. That does work but realised it works only when the struct Response definition is in the same package. It is giving an empty struct if the definition of the struct is in a different package. Also, the field of the struct Message is already exported (starts with a capital letter)

Comment: Behavior is same wherever the struct is located, since you create an variable and supply to decode. Can you please add the code to the question at the end?

Comment: Ok. We had some generated easy json things because of which it wasn't working. Anyway, ur solution is correct. Thanks a lot.